# How to retrieve attributes from has_one association without belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, redmine-plugins

I have several nested classes that look like so:

```
class Presentation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :campaign_records, :as => :campaignable

  def campaign_records_text(joiner)
    return '' if self.campaign_records.blank?
    self.campaign_records.map {|c| c.to_s}.join(joiner)
  end
end

class CampaignRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaignable, :polymorphic => true
  has_one :campaign
  has_one :tier_one
  has_one :tier_two

  def to_s
    "#{campaign.name} - #{tier_one.name} - #{tier_two.name}"
  end
end

class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tier_ones

   attr_accessible :name
end

class TierOne < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tier_twos
   belongs_to :campaign

   attr_accessible :name
end

class TierTwo < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :tier_one

   attr_accessible :name
end
```

In summary, a `Campaign` has many associated `TierOne`s and every `TierOne` has it's own set of `TierTwo`s. A `Presentation` has a set of `CampaignRecord`s which link a `Campaign`,`TierOne`, and `TierTwo` together. Note though that a `Campaign` **does not belong_to** a `CampaignRecord` because many `CampaignRecord`s can refer to it.

So here's the problem: I want to change the `CampaignRecord.to_s` method to return "`campaign.name` - `tier_one.name` - `tier_two.name`" (like shown above) but doing so results in an error when I try to call `some_campaign_record.to_s`:

> ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column
>   'campaigns.campaign_record_id' in 'where clause': SELECT 'campaigns'.*
>   FROM 'campaigns' WHERE 'campaigns'.'campaign_record_id' = # LIMIT 1)

Where did I go wrong here? I know that rails auto generates a lot of getters and setters for me, but the default `to_s` method is just the usual  so how do I override it in the proper rails way? Does a `has_one` require a `belongs_to` or is there a `belongs_to_many` hiding out there somewhere that I should have used instead?

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

(Also, I saw that my question is very similar to [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27029883/968370))

**EDIT**

I'm seeing a bit of confusion about the model structure here so let me try to explain it differently in a way that will hopefully be clearer.

First off, just to be clear a `Campaign` is **very different** from a `CampaignRecord`.

Think of the Campaign-TierOne-TierTwo relationship like a three layered list:

1. Campaign 1

   - TierOne 1.1

     - TierTwo 1.1.1
     - TierTwo 1.1.2
     - ...
   - TierOne 1.2

     - TierTwo 1.2.1
     - TierTwo 1.2.2
     - ...
   - ...
2. Campaign 2

   - TierOne 2.1

     - TierTwo 2.1.1
     - TierTwo 2.1.2
     - ...
   - TierOne 2.2

     - TierTwo 2.2.1
     - TierTwo 2.2.2
     - ...
   - ...
3. Campaign 3
   ...

The CampaignRecord model is a representation of a Campaign, TierOne, TierTwo tuple. When its first created, you select a Campaign. Then select a TierOne from that Campaign's set of TierOnes. Then a TierTwo from that TierOne's set of TierTwos. In other words, the CampaignRecord model is a path which traverses a Campaign-TierOne-TierTwo tree.

The set of `presentation.campaign_records` is the set of valid Campaign-TierOne-TierTwo paths which a user has previously associated with that presentation instance. (A Presentation will have zero or more of these paths associated with it.)

The important bit of functionality is that a Presentation should have a variable size set of Campaign-TierOne-TierTwo linkages. While modifying any given Presentation, I need to be able to modify/add/remove Campaign-TierOne-TierTwo linkages to/from a Presentation. I chose to represent those Campaign-TierOne-TierTwo linkages as `CampaignRecords`. A Presentation can have a bunch of these `CampaignRecords`, but no Campaign, TierOne, or TierTwo will ever `belong_to` a CampaignRecord.

So, my question becomes: Why is my `Campaign` model throwing a "can't find specified column" error when it was never supposed to be looking for that column in the first place?

```
@presentations = Presentations.all
@presentations.each do |presentation|
    presentation.campaign_records.each do |campaign_record|
        print campaign_record.to_s # Campaign model throws error here
    end
 end
```

Comment: i think `.to_s` is an your intance method and you are calling it om class.

Comment: So, one error that I see (but doesn't appear to relate to the error message you cited), is that Campaign is expecting to find a TierTwo with a campaign_id. Can you confirm that the TierTwo model has a campaign_id?

Comment: @LannyBose: No, the TierTwo model does not have a campaign_id.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above, one error I see is the following:

```
class CampaignRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_one :tier_two
  ...
end
```

Take a look at the [Rails Guide on Associations.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association). Campaign is going to expect to see a campaign_record_id in any ActiveRecord model that has a has_*something* association.

My best bet is that you'll want to add that column into the TierTwo database.

Alternately, if *every* TierTwo's CampaignRecord can be inferred through its TierOne, you could also hypothetically do:

```
class CampaignRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :tier_twos, through: :tier_one
  ...
end
```

However, that doesn't seem like the right option. You say a CampaignRecord has only one TierTwo, and TierOne can have *many* TierTwos.

Let me know if this helps. It's possible I'm missing some information about your business logic that would help clarify my recommendation.

Comment: Check out the edits I just added. I think I wasn't quite clear enough on how everything works together in my original post. The edits will hopefully clear that up.

Comment: Ahhhh... this makes it much clearer, and I now better understand which models to be scrutinizing. Thanks! So, the one challenge in your edit is that YES, it should be looking for that column. When in your CampaignRecord model you call campaign.to_s, the has_one relationship means it it looking over to Campaign. Can you show me your schema.rb to confirm its presence?

Comment: Figured it out. I'll post some code later when i'm at the office. Just had to use `belongs_to` in the CampaignRecord instead of `has_one`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution seems pretty obvious to me now, in hindsight. My CampaignRecord model had fields to store IDs of other model records. But the `has_one` in the CampaignRecord implies that other models should be storing the ID of the CampaignRecord. Solution was to change the `has_one`s to `belongs_to`s so that the lookup goes in the other direction:

```
class CampaignRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaignable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :campaign
  belongs_to :tier_one
  belongs_to :tier_two

  def to_s
    "#{campaign.name} - #{tier_one.name} - #{tier_two.name}"
  end
end
```